# How to set one component's state from another component in React

Tags: reactjs

Say I have the following component named Home:

```
this.state = {
    posts: []
}
componentDidMount() {
    ... data is fetched from api
}

<div
    <PostForm />
    {this.state.posts.map(post => (
     <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
    ))}
</div>
```

How would I update the state of Home, or re fetch data from the api after the the PostForm component is submitted with a new Post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

**Setting the parent state from the child:**

If you want your child component to have access to your parent component's state, just pass `setState()` as a prop in your parent class, like so...

```
<PostForm
    setParentState={(state) => this.setState(state)}
/>
```

Then, later in `PostForm.js`, just set the parent state like so....

```
this.props.setParentState(newParentStateObject);
```

Or, you can even just do....

```
<PostForm
    postform={this}
/>
```

And later on, you can call anything in postform with `this.props.postform.anyFunctionEver()`.

**Setting the child state from the parent:**

Suppose you want to do the opposite now: update the state of the child component from the parent?  That's just as easy, set a reference when defining `<PostForm/>`...

```
<PostForm
    ref={(instance) => {this.postform = instance}}
/>
```

Then you can set the postform's state directly in your parent class...

```
this.postform.setState(newChildStateObject);
```

A lot can happen with the state, so if you're not sure, try making a `testFunc() {console.log('test');}`, and then try passing/activating this between parent and child.