# React components communication when using a dynamic value in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React to fetch an API to display data after clicking on buttons. Each button is a category, once clicked it shows cards for that category only.

I would like to know how to communicate between components to have one component with the buttons and one component with the data from one category without having to call the API twice and just passing the value for the category.

The value of the button is a dynamic value passed inside the API call and I am not sure how to communicate between the buttons components and the display of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

The routing component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from '../components/NavBar/NavBar'
import HomeButtons from './HomeButtons/HomeButtons';
import CardsCategory from './CardsCategory/CardsCategory';
import CardsProps from './CardsCategory/CardsProps'

class Routing extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route path="/" component={Navbar} />
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomeButtons} />
                <Route exact path="/cards" component={CardsProps} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Routing
```

The buttons component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import './HomeButtons.css';
import ButtonCategory from '../../components/ButtonCategory/ButtonCategory'

class HomeButtons extends Component {

    handleClick = (buttonValue) => {
        // only 3 first letters of the button to match category in the API:
        buttonValue = buttonValue.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase();
        axios.get('http://api.nobelprize.org/2.0/nobelPrizes?sort=desc&nobelPrizeCategory=' + buttonValue + '&format=json&csvLang=en')
            .then(res => {
                const categoryData = res.data.nobelPrizes;
                // console.log("CATEGORY", categoryData?.category?.en)
                this.setState({
                    category: buttonValue
                })
            }).
            catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
    render() {
        const allCategoriesButtons = ["Physics", "Chemistry", "Medicine", "Literature", "Peace", "Economics"];
        const allCatMap = allCategoriesButtons.map(button =>
            < ButtonCategory
                key={button.toString()}
                value={button}
                name={button}
                onClick={e => this.handleClick(e.target.value)}
            />
        )

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container__section">
                    {allCatMap}
                </div >
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HomeButtons;
```

The cards data component with a hard coded category in the API call :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import WinnerCard from '../../components/WinnerCard/WinnerCard'

class Cards extends Component {
    state = {
        allCards: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://api.nobelprize.org/2.0/nobelPrizes?sort=desc&nobelPrizeCategory=eco&format=json&csvLang=en')
            .then(res => {
                const categoryData = res.data.nobelPrizes;
                this.setState({
                    allCards: categoryData,
                    // category: buttonValue
                })
            }).
            catch(err => console.log(err))
    };


    render() {

        const cards = this.state.allCards.map((card) => {
            return <WinnerCard
                key={card.id}
                awardYear={card.awardYear}
                category={card.category.en}
                name={card.laureates[0].knownName?.en}
                motivation={card.laureates[0].motivation?.en}
            />
        })

        return (
            <div>
                {cards}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Cards
```

Comment: Hi, Etwck_380!  Welcome to SO!  I have an answer on a similar question, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549), hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Communication between **SIBLING** components can be achieved using **[FBEMITTER](https://github.com/facebook/emitter)** but that would IMHO make the structure a little confusing with multiple components interacting at multiple levels.

However, it feels like you might want to take a different approach something like below, just a thought.

Since you have routes defined for the cards tab, I think it's best, if you could send the category as a parameter in the URL itself, something like `/cards/:category_name`.

Changes go about like this

```
class Routing extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route path="/" component={Navbar} />
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomeButtons} />
                <Route exact path="/cards/:category_name" component={Cards} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Routing
```

**HomeButtons**

Here, instead of setting the state inside the axios then, you can just re route your application to `/cards/:category_name`

```
handleClick = (buttonValue) => {
    // only 3 first letters of the button to match category in the API:
    buttonValue = buttonValue.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase();
    axios.get('http://api.nobelprize.org/2.0/nobelPrizes?sort=desc&nobelPrizeCategory=' + buttonValue + '&format=json&csvLang=en')
        .then(res => {
            ---------------------------------------
            Change the route to /cards/<buttonValue> 
            ---------------------------------------
        }).
        catch(err => console.log(err))
};
```

**Cards**

```
class Cards extends Component {
    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://api.nobelprize.org/2.0/nobelPrizes?sort=desc&nobelPrizeCategory=eco&format=json&csvLang=en')
            .then(res => {
                const categoryData = res.data.nobelPrizes;
                this.setState({
                    allCards: categoryData,
                    category: <fetch category from the API that your router provides>
                })
            }).
            catch(err => console.log(err))
    };


    render() {
        ...
    }
}

export default Cards
```