# How can I pass a mapbox coordinates to a parent class in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to set a marker on a mapbox gl map with a click on the map and then pass the lngLat object back up to the parent component. Please tell me how I can do this. I'm new to learning react but I know props can only be inherited from the parent class and setState only sets the local state.

```
   // add a marker when user clicks a point
    map.on("click", "random-points-layer", e => {
      if (e.features.length) {
        const feature = e.features[0];
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
      // e.point is the x, y coordinates of the mousemove event relative
      // to the top-left corner of the map
        JSON.stringify(e.point) +
        '<br />' +
       // e.lngLat is the longitude, latitude geographical position of the event
        JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.wrap());

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//   add a marker to the map
        var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      }
    });
```

The parent component looks like this

```
  render() {
     <div>
      <h1>Activate a beacon<h1/>
      <Map/>
     <div/>
}
```

I'm following this tutorial   https://github.com/laneysmith/react-mapbox-example

Comment: Hi, John!  I just answered a very, very similar question -- [Passing a Ref from a Child to a Parent in React with Class Component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477269/2430549).  This shows how to use references of child components to share functions or component data/state, I think this is probably right for you.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou for the help. Your answer on the other question was really helpful

Comment: Hey, John!  Excellent!  I've updated my answer below with a link to that other question, too.  Don't forget, if it's helpful, you can mark it as accepted, so others will know where to look!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your child component like so in your parent class...

```
<ChildComponent
    parent={this}
/>
```

Then call your parent class functions in your child class...

```
this.props.parent.someFunction();
```

[**Full working demo.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-gg9wk?file=/index.js)  In this example, the child displays the parent's `id` field, but it could have been a function call, as well, and in the function call, I could include whatever arguments I'd like to pass from child to parent function.

I have an answer to a similar question, if you are curious: [Passing a Ref from a Child to a Parent in React with Class Component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477269/2430549).