# React in render method cant read this.props.location.state"

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I learn React and now I cant figure out how to do this I get:

> Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

on the line:

```
  if (album.route === this.props.location.state.week) {
```

This is the render:

```
 render() {
        
    let photosArr = []
    albums.map((album) => {
      if (album.route === this.props.location.state.week) {
        album.data.forEach((photo) => {
          photosArr.push([photo.id, photo.src])
        })
      }
    })
    this.state.items = photosArr
    console.log(this.props.location)
```

I'm calling it like this using `import { withRouter } from "react-router";`:

```
onImageClick = val => {
    const {history} = this.props;
    history.push("/timeLineViewer", val);
  };
```

And it works if I remove the `albums.map((album..` code then the `console.log....` show the props vale

The problem is that the `rendered` gets called before I make the call to updated the props from `onImageClick` so I get the above error if I have the `this.props.location.state.week.`.

How can I handle this since `this.props.location.state` don't exist before I call `onImageClick`

Comment: How are you sending props to your `<Component .../>`?  i.e. `<Component prop1=prop1var prop2=prop2var>`?

Comment: The Component is a image gallery just waiting for props to know what album to show. I send the props in the `onImageClick`

Comment: It would be nice to see the code setting the props, since you're getting `undefined` when calling the prop.  Also, this answer might help you: [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I handle this since this.props.location.state don't exist before I call onImageClick

Javascript throws an error since you are trying to get a property of undefined. So you should handle the undefined case.

Replace:

```
if (album.route === this.props.location.state.week)
```

with:

```
if (album.route === this.props.location?.state?.week)
```

Or :

```
if (this.props.location &&
    this.props.location.state &&
    album.route === this.props.location.state.week)
```