# How to handle parameters between parent component and child component

Tags: reactjs

This is working perfectly as a single component. I am trying to remove the search function because I render the component in another component which is embedded in a list. I don't want the search to appear in multiple places. I want to separate it and put it in a parent component.
I don't know how to handle this. I have tried to use props, probably I am doing it the wrong way.

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react'
    
    
    function TagsInput(props) {
        const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
        const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    
    
        const addTags = event => {
            if (event.key === "Enter" && event.target.value !== "") {
                setTags([...tags, event.target.value]);
                props.selectedTags([...tags, event.target.value]);
                event.target.value = "";
            }
        };
    
        const removeTags = index => {
            setTags([...tags.filter(tag => tags.indexOf(tag) !== index)]);
        };
        
    
    
        const handleFilterChange = e => {
            setSearch(e.target.value)
      }
    
       function  DataSearch(rows) {
            return rows.filter((row) => row.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        }
        const  searchPosts = DataSearch(tags);
    
        return (
            <> 
            <div>
                <input value={search} onChange={handleFilterChange} placeholder={"Search"} /> 
            </div>
            <div className="tags-input">
             <ul>
                {searchPosts.map((tag, index) => (
                   <li key={index}>
                      <span>{tag}</span>
                      <i 
                        className="material-icons"
                        onClick={() => removeTags(index)}
                       >x</i>
                   </li>
                ))}
             </ul>
             <input 
             type="text" 
             onKeyUp={event => addTags(event)}
             placeholder="Press enter to add tags" />
          </div>
          </>
        )
    }
    
    export default TagsInput
```

I am using this component in another component. I want to remove the search input but I don't know how to do it as it is component of a function not defined.

```
<div>
        <input value={search} onChange={handleFilterChange} placeholder={"Search"} /> 
    </div>
```

**In the parent component**

`<TagsInput />` is embedded in it map function and I want avoid the search being created in multiple li.

Thank you and I am sorry for dump question as I am new to it.

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62365616/2430549).  The function in play in that question is `setState()`, but it could be any function/data shared between them.

Comment: You should consider adding an automatic code formatter to your workflow - something like prettier, which integrates with editors directly

Comment: No it didn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need from this component? If you just need to remove the search input box you can just remove

```
<div>
  <input
    value={search}
    onChange={handleFilterChange}
    placeholder={'Search'}
  />
</div>
```

It seems you are calling this component inside a parent component loop. If you just need to call this component once you have to use it outside the loop.

Comment: Well removing that div, removes search input field for me, if that is what you really want. If you have to use this component inside a map(), there isn't much you can do inside this component to stop rendering multiple times. Better to handle it inside the map function. For a example a variable to render the component only in first iteration.