# How to call a form onSubmit event from another Component in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am currently working on a funnel and on few pages, the user will have to upload files in order to progress in this funnel. My problem here is that the user navigate through the pages with buttons next and previous in a footer and I want my app to display the "invalid" feedback when the user click on next when the file upload is still empty.

Here is my page.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
//React-Bootstrap components import
import { Col, Container, Form, ProgressBar, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  Check2Circle,
  CloudUploadFill,
  ShieldLockFill,
} from "react-bootstrap-icons";
import { Footer } from "../../components/footer";
import PageTitle from "../../components/page_title";

class IdPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: this.props.file, //So if the user go back and come back on this page, the file stay in memory
    };

    this.onFormChange = this.onFormChange.bind(this);
  }
  nextPath() {
    if (this.state.file === null) { //here is my condition (quiet simple but efficient) to cancel the "next" button action
      return;
    }
    this.props.history.replace("6"); //I know that the replace function can be weird but I'll fix that later
  }
  previousPath(type) {
    this.props.history.replace("4");
  
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });
    this.props.onFileChange(e);
  }
  render() {
    const { type, service } = this.props;

    var label = (
      <span>
        <CloudUploadFill size={20} color={`${lightblue}`} />
        {"    "}Mon justificatif d’identité
      </span>
    );
    if (this.state.file) {
      label = this.state.file.name;
    }
    return (
    <>
        <Container style={{ marginBottom: "120px" }} fluid>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col lg={5} md={8} className="my-auto pt-4 main-fontsize">
              <PageTitle text={`Mon nouveau contrat ${service}`} />
              //Some text
              {/* Form input to upload id document */}
              <Form
                noValidate
                validated={this.state.validated}
                className="my-3"
              >
                <Form.File
                  id="custom-file"
                  label=label
                  data-browse="Choose"
                  onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
                  custom
                  required
                  isInvalid={!this.state.validated}
                >
                  <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                    //invalid message
                  </Form.Control.Feedback>
                </Form.File>
                <Form.Text style={{ color: `${blue}` }}>
                  This file needs to be a pdf file or an image
                </Form.Text>
              </Form>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <Footer
          nextPage={() => this.nextPath()}
          previousPage={() => this.previousPath(type)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(IdPage);
```

And if you need it, here is my footer.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Button, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

export const Footer = (props) => {
  let previousButtonValue =
    props.previousButtonValue === undefined ? "Previous" : "" ;
  let bluebuttonvalue =
    props.buttonValue === undefined ? "Next" : props.buttonValue;
  return (
    <footer
      className="site-footer shadow-lg"
      style={{
        position: "fixed",
        bottom: 0,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "white",
      }}
    >
      <Container className="py-3" fluid>
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-between my-auto">
            <p className="ml-2 my-auto">
              <a
                className="primary"
                onClick={props.previousPage}
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              >
                <u>{previousButtonValue}</u>
              </a>
            </p>
            <Button
              className="text-right rounded-pill"
              onClick={props.nextPage}
            >
              {bluebuttonvalue}
            </Button>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </Container>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default {
  Footer,
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have an answer to a very similar question, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549), it's about sharing `setState()`, but you can use any function, really.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that I understand your issue but will try to help.

What kind of feedback do you need to display?

As I see you already have a function which is handling the next:

```
  nextPath() {
if (this.state.file === null) {
  return;
}
this.props.history.replace("6");
```

}

You can handle whatever you need from here. You have the information you need in here.

However it would be helpful to concretely know what kind of feedback you want. What are you trying to do?

Should the feedback be in the footer itself?

If that's the case I think you have all the information you need already in your component. You know when a file has been uploaded. Just pass that information to the footer as a prop and handle this feedback there.

```
<Footer
  isNextEnabled={!!this.state.file}
  nextPage={() => this.nextPath()}
  previousPage={() => this.previousPath(type)}
/>
```

Something like this. In your Footer you have now the info to display whatever feedback is needed.

Tell me if I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: I want to display Form.Control.Feedback bellow the file upload, it's a text which is supposed to appear and say "Sorry, you need to provide a document before going further".
For the moment, as you know the user can't go further but I want to give hilm more information about why I can't go further.