# how to pass an event from a child component to parent component back down to another child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say for instance that I have three components in React, an App (the parent component), a button component and a component that is meant to display something, can be anything doesn't really matter. Lets say in the button component is activated, how would I pass the information (ie that the event actually happened) to the App parent component back down to the other child component to let it know a specific event happened to display some message?

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question here, except what is being shared between the components is the `setState()` between them.  Understanding this should hopefully help you understand the problem fundamentals: [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549)

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would go about dong this using hooks :

```
const Parent=(props)=>{
 [eventHappend,setEventHappend]=useState(false)
 return (
  <div>
     <Child1 setEventHappend={setEventHappend} />
     <Child2 eventHappend={eventHappend} />
  </div>
)
}


const Child =({setEventHappend})=>{
 return (
  <div>
     <button onClick={e=>setEventHappend(true)} > click me 1 </button>
  </div>
)
}


const Child2 =({eventHappend})=>{
 
 return (
  <div>
     <button onClick={e=>{/* some code*/ }} > {eventHappend?'event happend':'event didnt happen yet '} </button>
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: You can use rxjs subject to communicate between any two components of your application

Comment: this is a simple and  beginner friendly answer , and its doing the job why would implement something more advance such as rxjs ?

Comment: you might as well recommend redux in that case

Comment: RXJS permits lifecycles for hooks outside of components' mounted lifespan by modular service definitions

Comment: hey @LoveenDyall check my other answer I implemented Rxjs

Comment: hey @ShrutiB check my other answer I implemented Rxjs

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can achieve this pass state as props to the child elements (must know before other methods), context or use redux which has a store.

Generally speaking. React has one way data flow, uni directional. As in the parent will hold the state and will be passed to child elements.

Here App holds the state buttonClick which has the information about the event.

```
const App = () => {
const [ buttonClick, setButtonClick] = React.useState(false);
const messageToBeDispalyed = "The button has been clicked"
return (
<div>
<CustomButton setEventHappened={setButtonClick} />
<DisplayText  value = {buttonClick ? messageToBeDispalyed : ""} />
</div>
 )
}

const CustomButton = (props) =>{
return <button onClick={(e)=>props.setEventHappened(true)} >  Click Me </button>
}

const DisplayText = (props) => {
return <h1> {props.value} </h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar answers to the others, but you would pass down a method to the child from the parent to update the state. But be aware that by doing this will cause a rerender for all of the parent's children.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = value => {
    setState(value);
  };

  return (
    <Child state={state} handleClick={handleClick} />
    <OtherChild isTrue={state} /> // this component needs data changed by <Child />
  )
};
const Child = props => {
  const {state, handleClick} = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleClick(!state)} >click me</button>
  );
};
```

This way the parent alone handles the state change and provides that method to the child.

Answer (score 0):

as @Loveen Dyall and @Shruti B  mentioned  you can use RXJS for a more modular approach ,While RxJS is typically thought of as being used with Angular projects, it's a completely separate library that can be used with other JavaScript frameworks like React and Vue.

When using RxJS with React, the way to communicate between components is to use an Observable and a Subject (which is a type of observable), I won't go too much into the details about how observables work here since it's a big subject, but in a nutshell there are two methods that we're interested in: Observable.subscribe() and Subject.next().
learn more about RXJS and Observables : https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-rxjs-observables/

Observable.subscribe()
The observable subscribe method is used by React components to subscribe to messages that are sent to an observable.

Subject.next()
The subject next method is used to send messages to an observable which are then sent to all React components that are subscribers (a.k.a. observers) of that observable.

here is how you implement it in this use case :
this is called a service and  you would put this file in a services folder

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
const subject = new Subject();

//here where sending { event: eventTitle } , that way you can listen to diffrent events , for example 'INCREMENTED' you could even send values 
export const eventsService= {
    sendEvent: eventTitle => subject.next({ title: eventTitle }),
    getEventNotification: () => subject.asObservable()
};
```

in your Child 1 component you would subscribe to the observable in useEffect or compoentDidMount if your using class component:

```
import { eventsService} from '../services';
const Child1 =()=>{
  const [child2EventFired,setChild2EventFired]=useState(false)
  useEffect(()=>{
      let subscription = eventsService.getEventNotification().subscribe(eventTitle => 
          {
            if (eventTitle=="CHILD2_BUTTON_CLICK" ) {
               setChild2EventFired(true)
            }else{
                setChild2EventFired(false)
             }
        });
      return ()=>{
       subscription.unsubscribe();
     }
    },[])

    return <div>
         <button> {child2EventFired? 'child2 button event fired':'event not fired yet'} </button>
    </div> 
}
```

in your Child 2 component

```
import { eventsService} from '../services';
const Child2 =()=>{
    Child2Click=(e)=>{
        //some code, 
        //then send messages to the observable observable
        eventsService.sendEvent('CHILD2_BUTTON_CLICK');
    }

    return <div>
         <button onClick={Child2Click} >click me</button>
    </div> 
}
```