# draft.js: text editor populate value from other component's state

Tags: reactjs, state, draftjs

I'm using `draft.js` to make a text editor and I have two components: `CreatePost.js` which gets the post fields from the back end and populates the state with the user input and `TextEditor.js` which contains a text editor which I am using in `CreatePost.js`. The text editor should populate the `body` field in the state of `CreatePost.js` onChange.

My question is how can I get the text editor to populate the state in the other component? Would I need to use props instead?

Before, I had a text area in `CreatePost.js` which populated the `body`. I want the text editor in the other component to populate it instead. I've tried using
`<TextEditor onChange={this.changeHandler} value={body} />` in `CreatePost.js` but it didn't work.

`console.log(body)`:
[image]

posts.js (controller)

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const { title, body, date } = req.body;
  const post = new Post({
    title,
    body,
    date,
    "author.id": req.profile._id,
    "author.name": req.profile.name,
  });
  post
    .save()
    .then((response) => {
      res.send(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler(err),
      });
    });
};
```

CreatePost.js

```
class CreatePost extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      body: "",
      createdPost: "",
      error: "",
    };
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      user: { _id },
    } = isAuthenticated();
    axios({
      url: `${API}/post/new-post/${_id}`,
      method: "POST",
      data: this.state,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ createdPost: this.state.title });
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (!this.state.title || !this.state.body) {
          this.setState({
            error: "This post must contain a title and a body.",
          });
        }
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

...

  render() {
    const { title, body } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <Tabs>
          <TabList className="tabs">
            <Tab className="tab">Draft</Tab>
            <Tab className="tab">Preview</Tab>
          </TabList>
          <TabPanel>
            <div className="newpost_container">
              <form className="newpost_form" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Title"
                    name="title"
                    className="newpost_field newpost_title"
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    value={title}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group newpost_body">
                <TextEditor />
                </div>
                <button className="btn publish-post-btn" type="submit">
                  Publish
                </button>
                {this.showSuccess()}
                {this.showError()}
              </form>
            </div>
          </TabPanel>

          <TabPanel>
            <div>
              <h1>{title}</h1>
              <div>{body}</div>
            </div>
          </TabPanel>
        </Tabs>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default CreatePost;
```

TextEditor.js

```
class TextEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    };
    this.plugins = [addLinkPlugin];
  }
  toggleBlockType = (blockType) => {
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(this.state.editorState, blockType));
  };

  onChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  handleKeyCommand = (command) => {
    const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(
      this.state.editorState,
      command
    );
    if (newState) {
      this.onChange(newState);
      return "handled";
    }
    return "not-handled";
  };

// onClick for format options

  onAddLink = () => {
    const editorState = this.state.editorState;
    const selection = editorState.getSelection();
    const link = window.prompt("Paste the link -");
    if (!link) {
      this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleLink(editorState, selection, null));
      return "handled";
    }
    const content = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentWithEntity = content.createEntity("LINK", "MUTABLE", {
      url: link,
    });
    const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
      editorState,
      contentWithEntity,
      "create-entity"
    );
    const entityKey = contentWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleLink(newEditorState, selection, entityKey));
  };

  toggleBlockType = (blockType) => {
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(this.state.editorState, blockType));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="editorContainer">
        <div className="toolbar">
          <BlockStyleToolbar
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            onToggle={this.toggleBlockType}
          />
          // format buttons
        </div>

        <div>
          <Editor
            placeholder="Post Content"
            blockStyleFn={getBlockStyle}
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            plugins={this.plugins}
            placeholder="Post Content"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TextEditor;
```

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question, here: [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549)  This should help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've been quite close to solving this actually. You were on the right path when sending down the change handler using props to the `TextEditor`. One solution to your problem is to move up the `editorState` to your `CreatePost` component and then pass the value and the change handler downwards. If you are doing this you should remove the editorState and the change handler for it from the `TextEditor` file. Just by continuing on your example something like this should work, I haven't tried the code out but it should help you in the right direction.

In `CreatePost.js`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      body: EditorState.createEmpty(),
      createdPost: "",
      error: "",
    };
}

....

<TextEditor onChange={(value) => this.setState({ body: value })} editorState={body} />
```

In `TextEditor.js`

```
<Editor
  placeholder="Post Content"
  blockStyleFn={getBlockStyle}
  editorState={this.props.editorState}
  handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
  onChange={this.props.onChange}
  plugins={this.plugins}
  placeholder="Post Content"
/>
```

When posting the data we need to access the content of the editor instead of the `EditorState`. We can do this through draft.js API (see more here: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state/#getcurrentcontent). And that's not enough unfortunately. We also need to to convert the content to a format that's easier to handle. We can do this with draft.js `convertToRaw` which you also need to import from the library (https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion/#converttoraw). Convert to raw returns a JS object so we also need to convert that to a string before being able to send it to the server by using `JSON.stringify()`.

```
axios({
  url: `${API}/post/new-post/${_id}`,
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    ...this.state,
    body: JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(this.state.body.getCurrentContent()))
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've implemented the code and it has helped a lot! Although the text formatting works, `body` still doesn't contain the value unfortunately and therefore the post isn't saved to the db. I have updated my question with the output of `console.log(body)`.

Comment: Okey that's good! I understand. I think the "new" issue is because we are not getting the actual text content from the editor, we are actually only getting the `editorState` which is a bit different. I've added some more code with an example of how you can get the content of the editor as well. Instead of doing this directly in the state I think it's better to do it in the request. We still need to pass the `editorState` to the editor otherwise that will stop working.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! Unfortunately, that hasn't changed anything. I don't have any errors but I'm receiving `404` and the output is the same when I `console.log(body)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I skimmed through the documentation a bit too fast. We actually need to do two additional conversions before the data is in a format that we can send. First we need to use `convertToRaw` which is a function from draft.js. After that we need to use `JSON.stringify()` to get the data to a string instead. That should work. You might have to do something on your server as well as the data will still be related to draft.js formats. Regarding `404` that might have been caused by the wrong data format. `console.log(body)` will still be wrong as we are not updating the body state.

Comment: Thank you! The request is now returning `200` and `body` is being persisted to the db, however, it's returning the whole object wrapped in a string e.g: `{"blocks":[{"key":"1r6jb","text":"aaaaaaaaa","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}`  instead of just the text. I tried changing the code in the server but I don't understand what I need to change/add. I've updated my question with the `controller` in server.js.

Comment: If you look at the object you can see that one of the attributes you get is `text`. I guess that's what you are looking for. You could probably to something like `const arr = body.blocks.map(({ text }) => text)` to only get the text contents in an array. Then you could do something like `arr.join(' ')` to join all the texts with a space between. I don't think I can help you further than so because it will be very dependant on what you want and how the rest of your solution looks like. Good luck!

Comment: Okay great, thanks a lot for your help! I'll try different things and figure out the last part.