# tried every solution why this error occurs ? body: CastError: Cast to string failed for value mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

tried every solution  why this error occurs ? can not understand at all

i was trying to remove cloudinary upload section from website .

it means users can post in my blog without uploading image .

image was necessary
so i tried to change source code but this error not going away at any cost

```
 this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
[0]                                ^
[0]
[0] ValidationError: Post validation failed: body: Cast to string failed for value "{
[0]   _immutable: {
[0]     allowUndo: true,
[0]     currentContent: {
[0]       entityMap: {},
[0]       blockMap: [Object],
[0]       selectionBefore: [Object],
[0]       selectionAfter: [Object]
[0]     },
[0]     decorator: { _decorators: [Array] },
[0]     directionMap: { idih: 'LTR' },
[0]     forceSelection: false,
[0]     inCompositionMode: false,
[0]     inlineStyleOverride: null,
[0]     lastChangeType: 'insert-characters',
[0]     nativelyRenderedContent: null,
[0]     redoStack: [],
[0]     selection: {
[0]       anchorKey: 'idih',
[0]       anchorOffset: 5,
[0]       focusKey: 'idih',
[0]       focusOffset: 5,
[0]       isBackward: false,
[0]       hasFocus: false
[0]     },
[0]     treeMap: { idih: [Array] },
[0]     undoStack: [ [Object] ]
[0]   }
[0] }" (type Object) at path "body", image.publicId: Path `image.publicId` is required., image.url: Path `image.url` is required.
```

this is my postmodel.js that i remove required:true . but error is same

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { url: { type: String, required: true }, publicId: { type: String, required: true } },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    likes: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    unicorns: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    bookmarks: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    tags: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Tag' }],
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Comment' }],
    author: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

and this is my post controller that i was trying to change and remove the upload part from website but i could not after 3 days .

postcontroller .js

```
const Post = require('../model/Post');
const User = require('../model/User');
const Tag = require('../model/Tag');
const Comment = require('../model/Comment');
const cloudinary = require('../config/cloudinary');
const { uploadToCloudinary } = require('../utils/cloudinary');
const { getPostParams, unCapitalizeFirstLetter } = require('../helpers/string');
const { createTags, updateTags, deleteTags } = require('./tagsController');
const {
    likeNotification,
    removeLikeNotification,
    postNotification,
    removePostNotification,
} = require('./notificationsController');

const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const { title, file, body, tags, authorUsername } = req.body;

    const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(file, 'Posts');
    const author = await User.findOne({ username: authorUsername }).exec();

    const formattedTags = tags
        .trim()
        .split(',')
        .map(w => w.trim().replace(/ /g, '-'));

    const createdPost = await Post.create({
        title,
        image: { url, publicId },
        body,
        author: author._id,
    });

    author.followers.map(followerId => {
        (async () => {
            await postNotification(author._id, createdPost._id, followerId);
        })();
    });

    await createTags(formattedTags, createdPost);

    author.posts.push(createdPost._id);

    await author.save();

    res.status(200).json(createdPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const getPost = async (req, res) => {
    const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const authorId = await author?.toObject({ getters: true }).id;
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

    const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
        author: authorId,
        title: postTitle,
        _id: postId,
    })
        .populate('author')
        .populate('comments')
        .populate('tags')
        .exec();

    res.status(200).json(foundPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
    const { userId } = req.params;

    const posts = await Post.find(userId ? { bookmarks: userId } : {})
        .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
        .populate('author')
        .populate('tags');
    if (!posts) res.status(204).json('No posts found');

    res.status(200).json(posts.map(post => post.toObject({ getters: true })));
};

const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
    const authorId = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

    const { url, public_id: publicId } = await uploadToCloudinary(req.body.image.url, 'Posts');

    await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.image.publicId);

    req.body.image = { url, publicId };
    const formattedTags = req.body.tags
        .trim()
        .split(',')
        .map(w => w.trim().replace(/ /g, '-'));

    const post = await Post.findOne({
        author: authorId,
        title: postTitle,
        _id: postId,
    })
        .populate('author')
        .populate('tags');

    Object.keys(req.body).map(key => {
        if (key !== 'tags') post[key] = req.body[key];
    });

    await updateTags(formattedTags, post);

    await post.save();

    res.status(200).json(post.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const deletePostsByUserId = async user => {
    const { _id: userId } = user;

    user.comments.forEach(commentId => {
        (async () => {
            await Post.updateMany({ comments: commentId }, { $pull: { comments: commentId } });
        })();
    });

    const posts = await Post.find({ author: userId }).populate('tags');

    ['likes', 'unicorns', 'bookmarks'].forEach(k => {
        (async () => {
            await Post.updateMany({ [k]: userId }, { $pull: { [k]: userId } });
        })();
    });

    posts.forEach(post => {
        (async () => {
            await deleteTags(
                post.tags.map(({ name }) => name),
                post,
                true
            );
            await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(post.image.publicId);
            await Post.deleteOne({ _id: post._id });
        })();
    });

    await Comment.deleteMany({ author: userId });
};

const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(req.params.postUrl);

    await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.body.publicId);

    const foundPost = await Post.findOne({
        author: author._id,
        title: postTitle,
        _id: postId,
    })
        .populate('tags')
        .exec();

    if (!foundPost) return res.sendStatus(204);

    const comments = await Comment.find({ parentPost: postId }).populate({
        path: 'author',
        populate: 'followers',
    });

    comments.forEach(({ author }) =>
        (async () => {
            author.comments.forEach(comment => author.comments.pull(comment));
        })()
    );
    author.posts.pull(postId);
    await author.save();

    await Comment.deleteMany({ parentPost: postId });

    await deleteTags(
        foundPost.tags.map(({ name }) => name),
        foundPost,
        true
    );

    removePostNotification(author._id, foundPost._id, author.followers);

    await Post.deleteOne({ _id: foundPost._id });

    res.status(200).json(foundPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

const postReaction = async (req, res) => {
    const { userId } = req.body;
    const { action, postUrl } = req.params;
    const { postTitle, postId } = getPostParams(postUrl);
    const isUndoing = action.includes('remove');
    const actionKey = isUndoing
        ? unCapitalizeFirstLetter(action.replace('remove', '')) + 's'
        : action + 's';

    const author = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username }).exec();
    const authorId = await author.toObject({ getters: true }).id;

    const updatedPost = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
        { author: authorId, title: postTitle, _id: postId },
        isUndoing ? { $pull: { [actionKey]: userId } } : { $addToSet: { [actionKey]: userId } },
        { new: true, timestamps: false }
    );

    if (isUndoing) await removeLikeNotification(userId, updatedPost._id, authorId);
    else await likeNotification(userId, updatedPost._id, authorId);

    res.status(200).json(updatedPost.toObject({ getters: true }));
};

module.exports = {
    createPost,
    getPosts,
    getPost,
    updatePost,
    deletePost,
    deletePostsByUserId,
    postReaction,
};
```

and this is my front end part new-post.jsx

```
import 'easymde/dist/easymde.min.css';
import { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import SimpleMDE from 'react-simplemde-editor';
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import Error from '../../common/Error';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../common/LoadingSpinner';
import RouteWrapper from '../../common/RouteWrapper';
import socketContext from '../../context/SocketContext';
import { selectCurrentUser } from '../../core/features/auth/authSlice';
import { useCreatePostMutation } from '../../core/features/posts/postsApiSlice';
import { useGetUserDashboardQuery } from '../../core/features/users/usersApiSlice';
import useBase64 from '../../hooks/useBase64';
import useRequireAuth from '../../hooks/useRequireAuth';
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
// import "../../../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
// import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "../NewPost/react-draft-wysiwyg.css"
// import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.cs";

// import LiveMarkdown from '../markdowneditor/markdowneditor';
// import  EasyMDE from 'easymde';

const NewPost = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');
  const [body, setBody] = useState('');
  const [tags, setTags] = useState('');
  const [isTagsFocused, setIsTagsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [inputsFilled, setInputsFilled] = useState(false);
  const filePickerRef = useRef();
  const titleRef = useRef();
  const [createPost, { isLoading, isError }] = useCreatePostMutation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const currentUser = useSelector(selectCurrentUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const previewURL = useBase64(file);
  const { isAuthed, handleAuth } = useRequireAuth();
  const { socket } = useContext(socketContext);
  const { data: user } = useGetUserDashboardQuery(currentUser.username);


  useEffect(() => titleRef.current.focus(), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (title && body && tags) setInputsFilled(true);
    else setInputsFilled(false);
  }, [title, body, tags]);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (inputsFilled) {
      if (isAuthed) {
        try {
          const { id } = await createPost({
            title,
            file: previewURL,
            body,
            tags,
            authorUsername: currentUser.username,
          }).unwrap();

          socket.emit('post', {
            sender: currentUser,
            receivers: user?.followers,
            post: { title, id },
          });

          setTitle('');
          setFile('');
          setBody('');
          setTags('');

          navigate('/');
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      } else handleAuth();
    }
  };

  return (
    <RouteWrapper>
      <Wrapper>
        {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner />}
        {!isLoading && (
          <NewPostWrapper>
            <Heading>ایجاد پست جدید</Heading>
            <InputWrapper>
              <Label dir='rtl' htmlFor='title'>موضوع</Label>
              <Input
              
                dir='rtl'
                ref={titleRef}
                id='title'
                value={title}
                onBlur={e => setTitle(prev => prev.trim())}
                onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </InputWrapper>
            <InputWrapper>
              // <Input
                type='file'
                ref={filePickerRef}
                onChange={e => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                style={{ display: 'none' }}
                
              />
              <ImagePreview src={previewURL.toString()} alt='عکس انتخاب کنید' />
              <Button onClick={() => filePickerRef.current.click()}>انتخاب آواتار</Button>
            </InputWrapper>
            <InputWrapper2>

            
              {/* <SimpleMDE value={body} onChange={setBody} required /> */}
              
              <Editor 
               
               
                    
                    editorState={body}
                    toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
                    wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
                    editorClassName="editorClassName"
                    onEditorStateChange={setBody}
                    textAlignment="right"
                    placeholder="اینجا تایپ کنید"
                />;





            </InputWrapper2>
            <InputWrapper>
              <Label htmlFor='tags'>
                تگ ها
                {isTagsFocused && (
                  <Span>تگ ها با کاما جدا شده هست</Span>
                )}
              </Label>
              <Input
                id='tags'
                value={tags}
                onFocus={() => setIsTagsFocused(true)}
                onBlur={() => setIsTagsFocused(false)}
                onChange={e => setTags(e.target.value.replace(/ /g, ''))}
                required
              />
            </InputWrapper>
            <Submit onClick={handleSubmit}>تایید</Submit>
            {isError && <Error>خطاا در انجام عملیات . دوباره امتحان کنید</Error>}
            {!inputsFilled && <Error>تمام فیلدها اجباری هست</Error>}
          </NewPostWrapper>
        )}
      </Wrapper>
    </RouteWrapper>
  );
};

const Submit = tw.button`bg-lighter-gray hover:bg-light-gray rounded-md text-center py-2 px-1 w-full text-sm`;

const ImagePreview = tw.img`w-32 h-32 mx-auto border border-gray flex justify-center items-center text-center object-cover`;

const Input = tw.input`py-1 px-2 rounded-md outline-none border-2 border-solid border-gray focus:border-blue`;

const Label = tw.label`font-bold text-dark-gray`;

const Span = tw.p`inline ml-sm`;

const InputWrapper = tw.div`flex flex-col gap-2  `;

const Button = tw.button`bg-lighter-gray hover:bg-light-gray rounded-md text-center py-2 px-1 w-28 text-sm mx-auto`;

const Heading = tw.h1`text-dark-gray text-center`;

const NewPostWrapper = tw.div`bg-white w-3/5 mob:(w-full px-4) mx-auto py-20 px-8 [&>*:not(:last-child)]:mb-md`;

const Wrapper = tw.div`flex items-center`;

const InputWrapper2 = tw.div`border border-gray`;

export default NewPost;
```

i tried to remove file change and change . but this error not going away. please if some one know this answer help me

Comment: You set schema for `body` is to be string, but not passing just string to it. The object you are passing looks like [this](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/next/blob/f82f37fb33041e9326a1332ea104a2776257d732/packages/core/flow-lib/draft-js/EditorState.js.flow#L47), the API documentation [here](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state/). I infer, you are using `draft-js` (IDK?) with next plugin. I suggest you add a break point to the line `const { title, file, body, tags, authorUsername } = req.body;` and see what value does `req.body` has? The same should be done for every method.

Comment: u mean the problem is not url or nothing ablout cloudinary or image?  draft js is problem ?        this is my  code for draft.js .            <Editor 
               
               
                    
                    editorState={body}
                    toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
                    wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
                    editorClassName="editorClassName"
                    onEditorStateChange={setBody}
                    textAlignment="right"
                    placeholder="type here"
                />;

Comment: @JishanShaikh   i add the information file of my draft.js . u think that is problem not image?  i add the code to my question please can u see

Comment: Your image required: false is not causing the error, as you linked the topmost code block, type conversion to string of body is causing the error. The `body` that you are using in `req.body` is not the right body you are looking for (you are looking for the body of the editor, right?). The solution of your exact problem lies in the comments of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64792115/8458465). They were getting the same object in their body (the default object of TextEditor), not just string.

Comment: @JishanShaikh  3 hours i was fighting with this code . u was right problem is editor . i  saw the comment of that question an test but it was javascript my application is react not woking i do not know why  . iam nat so smart sorry  . i could not resolve . can u say it simple ?   i change my code to    <Editor 
                    editorState={value={body}}
                    toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
               
                />;   but nothing . i must find a new editor that had rtl option . too many hours . i can not

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is JavaScript or react, in this case the problem is just the body variable in the schema. Maybe try renaming it and in all the legit instances that it has been used to a more semantic name, to define its actual purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occuring as you are trying to create a Post with no values but in your schema you have the values of title, body etc set as required and thus this error, check if you are calling the create Post from your frontend with no values.

Try to check this useEffect where you set your inputsfilled, I bet it sets the inputsfilled true even if the values are empty.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (title && body && tags) setInputsFilled(true);
    else setInputsFilled(false);
  }, [title, body, tags]);
```

The backend error is because the you are trying to create Post with required params but with empty values.

Hopefully this helps. This might even not be the problem. My bad if I got it wrong.