# how to pass data from one components to another using context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Here I have currencyOption which i want to pass to the another component

```js
 <div className="App">
      <h1>Convert Currency</h1>
      <OptionProvider value={currencyOptions}>
        <CurrencyRow currencyOptions={currencyOptions} />
        <SiConvertio className="convert" />
        <CurrencyRow currencyOptions={currencyOptions} />
      </OptionProvider>
    </div>
```

```js
<Container>
      <OptionConsumer>
        <Row>
          <Input type="number" className="input" />
          <select>
            {{currencyOptions.map((option) => (
              <option> {option} </option>
            ))}}
          </select>
        </Row>
      </OptionConsumer>
    </Container>
```

Here i want to receive that data which is passed . how can i do that

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question elsewhere, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549).  And if you know how to set another component's state, getting that state is trivially easy.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using function components, I'd recommend using the `useContext` hook, which I personally find a bit easier to reason about: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Those docs also have a good example of using Context like you are in your snippets

Comment: Perhaps you could post an example of your own to steer OP towards the right direction? As it is your answer may as well be just a comment. Welcome to Stack Overflow though. It's great that you took the time to contribute.