# React: trigger event in child component by click on parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**Context:**

I want to trigger an event in a parents child component by an onClick on the parent element

Code:

Parent **PlantContainer:**

```
import React from "react";
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/ClipLoader";
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import ShowMetric from '../showMetric';


export default class PlantContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <Box>
        <h2>{this.props.plantName}</h2>
        <ShowMetric 
          setting={this.props.plantName + ".moisture"} 
          unit="%">Moisture:</ShowMetric>
        <ShowMetric 
          setting={this.props.plantName + ".conductivity"} 
          unit="%">Fertility:</ShowMetric>
      </Box>
    );
  }
}
```

Child **ShowMetric:**

```
import React from "react";
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/ClipLoader";
import resolvePath from 'object-resolve-path';


export default class ShowMetric extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      reading: 0,
    };
  }

  getData() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(URL_HERE, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) =>
      this.setState({
        reading: resolvePath(json, this.props.setting),
        isLoading: false,
      })
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <ClipLoader />;
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={this.getData}>
          {this.props.children + " "}
          <nobr>{`${this.state.reading.toFixed(1)} ${this.props.unit}`}</nobr>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Main **App.js:**

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import PlantContainer from './components/plantContainer';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container maxWidth="md">
          <Box className="flexBox">
            <PlantContainer plantName="Plant_1"/>
            <PlantContainer plantName="Plant_2"/>
          </Box>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Problem**

The above code works as expected, as `<ShowMetric/>` shows the information and reloads when I click on it.

Now I want to reload all `<ShowMetric/>` Elements in  `PlantContainer` (maybe trigger the getData() function for each of them) when I click the `<H2>` Element of `PlantContainer`.

I tried to find ways how to pass down events or informations to children, but since props can't change at runtime (?) and I don't think a reference would be the best way here, I am a bit at lost on how to implement this.

And as this is my very first react web App and endeavour into this framework please call out any fishy thing you can find in the code.

Comment: You can have a state something like loadData. Paas this state to ShowMetric components. You can change the value of loadData on click of H2.

Comment: thats what I initially tried but afaik the only way to pass it down would be as a property(?) so I had something like this in <ShowMetrics/> states: `loadData: this.props.loadData`. But it didn't work as the state in ShowMetric didn't update but in the Parent it did

Comment: got it. so I reimplemented the props and added this to my ShowMetric: `componentWillReceiveProps(){this.getData();}` now it works as expected, thanks!

Comment: You have to implement componentDidUpdate also where you can check if  `this.props.loadData` is changed or not in ShowMetrics

Comment: You should avoid using componentWillRecieveProps. Check `https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html`

Comment: Hey, welcome to ReactJS.  I have an answer elsewhere that should help, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549).  Of course, since 'setState()' is just a func call, the same logic should apply in your case in calling any function for handling an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the more elegant way to do this would be to store all the data in the parent component and pass it down to the children through the props.

Here is a possible solution (I used function components as it should be privileged over the class components) :

**PlantContainer**

```
function fetchData() {
  return fetch(URL_HERE, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
    },
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}

export default function PlantContainer(props) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    isLoading: false,
    'moisture': 0, 
    'conductivity': 0
  });

  function loadData() {
    setData({...data, isLoading: true});
    fetchData().then(json => {
      setData({
        isLoading: false,
        'moisture': resolvePath(json, `${props.plantName}.moisture`),
        'conductivity': resolvePath(json, `${props.plantName}.conductivity`)
      });
    });
  }
  
  React.useEffect(loadData, []);
  
  return (
    <Box>
      <h2 onClick={loadData}>{props.plantName}</h2>
      {data.isLoading && <ClipLoader/>}
      {!data.isLoading && (
        <ShowMetric
          reading={data['moisture']}
          unit="%">Moisture:</ShowMetric>
        <ShowMetric
          reading={data['conductivity']}
          unit="%">Fertility:</ShowMetric>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

**ShowMetric**

```
export default function ShowMetric(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children + " "}
      <nobr>{`${props.reading.toFixed(1)} ${props.unit}`}</nobr>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can retrieve all the data by calling the service a single time, it seems to be useless to reload only one metric, so I only give to opportunity to reload both metrics by clicking on the `h2` element.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the insights! React has so many ways to get to the same result, so its great to see how else one would do it. Yours makes absolutly sense and I will use it :)

Queston: I see you added the `plantName` as a Parameter to `PlantContainer` ist `plantName`  still a property in this case? is it good practice to add properties as parameters to the function heads?
I also see that you are not using a constructor and instead useState. is this just some kind of personal preference?

Comment: using `PlantContainer({plantName}){...}` or `PlantContainer(props){...}` (and using `props.plantName` in the component) is exactly the same thing. I edited my answer to use props instead of `{plantName}`. `({plantName})` is just a way to destructure the `props` object => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment .

Comment: As I said in my answer, function components should be privileged over class components, so yes I prefer using function component with hooks over class components with its constructor and lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 2):

The [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook is perfect to allow child components and refs.

### Fully working example with Typescript support too!:

[image: Edit affectionate-ben-q4ox51]

```js
//Child Component 

//Create your ref types here
export type RefHandler = {
  pressAlert: () => void;
  inputRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
};

const Child = forwardRef<RefHandler, Props>((props, ref) => {
  const submitRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  //Initialise your refs here
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    inputRef: inputRef,
    pressAlert: () => submitRef?.current?.click()
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Child Component</p>
      <input type="text" value="lorem ipsum" ref={inputRef} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => alert("Alert pressed")} ref={submitRef}>
        Alert
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

```js
//Parent 
export default function Parent() {
  const childRef = useRef<RefHandler>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Parent</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          alert(childRef?.current?.inputRef?.current?.value);
        }}
      >
        Read child input
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => childRef?.current?.pressAlert()}>
        Press child button
      </button>
      <hr />
      <Child ref={childRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```