# React : How to make my SearchBar render in another Page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 pages both are childrens from App.

_ NavbarComp.js

_ Home.js

Right now I have a functionnal SearchBar in my Home, I'd like to pass the values between NavbarComp & Home.

When I search from my NavbarComp, I'd like to have a render only on the Home page.

This is what it looks like so far.

I now need to remove my input button from Home, and pass the values between both pages Navbar & Home.

I dont think I can use props there, tho.. looking for solutions !

**NavbarComp.js**

```
import { Layout } from "antd";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "redux/auth/authActions";
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, Form, FormControl, Button, Row, Col, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const { Header } = Layout;

export const NavbarComp = ({input, setInput}) => {

    const history = useHistory();
  const cookie = Cookies.get('token');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const logMeOut = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(logout());
    history.push('/');
  }

    return (
  <>
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">

      <Form className="d-flex">
        <FormControl
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          className="mr-2"
          aria-label="Search"
          input={input}
        />
    </Navar>
   </>
  )
 }
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { v4 as uuid_v4 } from "uuid";

export const Home = () => {
    const connected = useSelector(state => state.auth.user)
    const [input, setInput] = React.useState('');
    const [flats, setFlats] = React.useState([]);
    const [flatsDefault, setFlatsDefault] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getListing('real_estates')
    }, [])

    const getListing = async (url) => {
        const config = {
            method: 'GET',
        };

        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/${url}`, config);
        const data = await response.json();
        
        setFlats(data)
        setFlatsDefault(data)
    };

    const updateInput = async (input) => {
        const filtered = flatsDefault.filter(flat => {
            return flat.title.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
        })
        setInput(input);
        setFlats(filtered);
    }

    return (
        <>
         <input 
         type='text'
     input={input}
     placeholder={"Search for properties"}
     onChange={(e) => updateInput(e.target.value)}
    />
            <div className="home-header">
                <div className="bg-img-desc">
                    <h1>List of real estates</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container" style={{ padding: '0 3.5rem' }}>
                <ul className="row">
                    {flats ? (
                        flats.map(flat => (
                            <li className="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4" key={uuid_v4()}>
                                <div className="card h-100">
                                    { flat.images_url && <img src={`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}${flat.images_url[0]}`} className="card-img-top" alt=""/> }
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h5>{flat.title}</h5>
                                        <p>Price : {flat.price} €</p>
                                        <p>location : {flat.location}</p>
                                        {connected && <Link to={`/real_estates/${flat.id}`} className="btn btn-primary">Details</Link>}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <h2>Loading...</h2>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </>)
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Layout } from 'antd';
import { NavbarComp } from "components/NavbarComp";
import { Home } from "pages/Home";
import Realestate from "pages/Realestate";
import NewRealestate from "pages/NewRealestate";
import { Other } from "pages/Other";
import { Login } from "pages/Login";
import { Register } from "pages/Register";
import Profile from "pages/Profile";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getUser } from 'redux/auth/authActions';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUser(Cookies.get('id')))
        console.log(user)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Layout className="layout" style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
            <Router>
                <NavbarComp />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/real_estates/:id">
                        <Realestate />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/new_real_estate">
                        <NewRealestate />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/other">
                        <Other />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/login" >
                        <Login />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/register" >
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/profile" >
                        <Profile user={user} />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You need search results to visible in Home.js and search bar in NavbarComp.js ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365616/how-to-set-one-components-state-from-another-component-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see three ways that you can implement to resolve this.

The first one is creating a context, so your state is going to be share through all your app. So when you change it inside your NavbarComp you will be able to get this value in another component.

The second one is similar to context but using redux. I saw that you are using redux in your project, you can share those values through redux.

The other way is to create a useState() inside your app component and pass it as props to your NavbarComp and your home. So this state will be shared between those two.

```
    function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);
    const [value, setValue] = useState()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUser(Cookies.get('id')))
        console.log(user)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Layout className="layout" style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
            <Router>
                <NavbarComp value={value} setValue={setValue}/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Home value={value} setValue={setValue}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/real_estates/:id">
                        <Realestate />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/new_real_estate">
                        <NewRealestate />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/other">
                        <Other />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/login" >
                        <Login />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/register" >
                        <Register />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/profile" >
                        <Profile user={user} />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default App;
```