# Passing the value of a clicked element in a child component into a button in a parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, a parent component and a child component. This child component is inside the parent component. Inside the child component, there's a tag that when it is clicked, a value is been stored in a separate state, Now when a button inside the parent component is clicked, the value that was stored inside a state in the child component should be printed to the console.

What I have here below

```
// import Checboxtest from "./Checkboxtest";
import "./styles.css";

const Child = ({ showresult, click }) => {
  const [clickedvalue, setClickedValue] = useState("");

  const ItemClicked = (e) => {
    setClickedValue("Yes");
    console.log(clickedvalue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>

      <span onClick={ItemClicked}>
        <input type="checkbox" /> clik me
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Parent() {
  const [clickedvalue, setClickedValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        When clicked on the button below, the value of the checkbox inside the
        child component should be display on the console.
      </h1>
      <button
        onCick={() => {
          console.log(clickedvalue);
        }}
      >
        See checkbox value
      </button>
      <Child clickedvalue={clickedvalue} setClickedValue={setClickedValue} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You've described the expected behaviour, but what issue are you having?

Comment: Yes, all have written to get it done was not working

Comment: But what part specifically isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have an answer elsewhere that might help, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549), cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is known as lifting up the state.
The `clickedValue` useState should be in the Parent component, then it should be passed onto the Child component `<Child clickedValue={clickedValue}/>`.
And as the onClick function, in this case, is in the child component you should also pass the setter method
`<Child clickedValue={clickedValue} setclickedvalue={setclickedvalue}/>`.

Edit #1 -
After looking at the code there were multiple minor issues that I saw
like in the onClick was misspelled as onCiked

Here's the modified working code

````
const Child = ({clickedvalue, showresult, setClickedValue }) => {
  
  const ItemClicked = (e) => {
    setClickedValue(e.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>

      <span onClick={ItemClicked}>
        <input type="checkbox" value={clickedvalue}/> clik me
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};


const Parent = () => {
  const [clickedvalue, setClickedValue] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        When clicked on the button below, the value of the checkbox inside the
        child component should be display on the console.
      </h1>
      <button onClick={()=>{console.log(clickedvalue)}}>See checkbox value</button>
      <Child clickedvalue={clickedvalue} setClickedValue = {setClickedValue}/>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: @Abdasihsn I edited my code above to what I have presently, please it still doesn't work. the button inside the parent component is still not working

Comment: following your method @Tarun, where will i declare my setclickedvalue ? parent component or child component

Comment: Hey, Saw this comment and I've edited my answer, have a look @slife

Answer (score 0):

you should lift up the state of the `Child` component as follow:

```
const Child = ({ showresult, setClickedValue }) => {
  
  const ItemClicked = (e) => {
    setclickedvalue("Yes");
    console.log(clickedvalue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>

      <span onClick={ItemClicked}>
        <input type="checkbox" /> clik me
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Parent() {
  const [clickedvalue, setclickedvalue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        When clicked on the button below, the value of the checkbox inside the
        child component should be display on the console.
      </h1>
      <button onCick={()=>{console.log(clickedvalue)}}>See checkbox value</button>
      <Child  setClickedValue = {setClickedValue}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is still not working after trying all the solutions here @Abdasihsn

Comment: @Tarun this is still not working

Comment: did you get any errors? please share the results so I can check it