# React Access Value in Functional Component from Class Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-functional-component

I am using a React module called react-semantic-ui-datepickers which I believe is based on react-datepicker. Either way, it's more of a generic React question. I've got my main class component and the date picker functional component in the same file. The date picker renders and works fine but I can't figure out **how** to access the actual value of the date picker inside the main class component.

Simplified version of the code can be seen below where I'm just console logging out the values of a few variables. Can anyone please give me a suggestion on the best way to access the selected date picker value from the class component?

```
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import SemanticDatepicker from 'react-semantic-ui-datepickers';
import { Message, Form, Icon, Button, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import 'react-semantic-ui-datepickers/dist/react-semantic-ui-datepickers.css';

class MyForm extends Component {
  state = {
    colour: 'Black',
    description: ''
  };

  onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state.colour); // Shows current colour field value.
    console.log(this.state.description); // Shows current description field value.
    console.log(); // How do I access the selected value of the date picker field??
  };

  render()  {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <Form.Field>
            <Form.Group>
            <Form.Field control='select' value={this.state.colour} onChange={event => this.setState({ colour: event.target.value })}>
              <option value='Black'>Black</option>
              <option value='Blue'>Blue</option>
              <option value='Green'>Green</option>
              <option value='Orange'>Orange</option>
            </Form.Field>
            <DatePicker />
            </Form.Group>
            <label>Description</label>
            <Form.TextArea value={this.state.description} onChange={event => this.setState({ description: event.target.value })} />
          </Form.Field>
          <Button icon='add' labelPosition='left' content='Add' primary />
        </Form>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

const DatePicker = () => {
  const [endDate, setNewDate] = useState(null);
  const onChange = (event, data) => setNewDate(data.value);

  return <SemanticDatepicker onChange={onChange} />;
};

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: The Datepicker component needs to report your main class component its data. Then pass it as a prop to your functional component.

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question elsewhere, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "lift up the state" of the date picker to where you need it, that is in `MyForm` component.

Then the `MyForm` component should pass a `onChange` handler down to the `DatePicker` component as a prop, which in turn will pass it to `SemanticDatePicker` — as a side note, you probably don't need the `DatePicker` component anymore, since it becomes an empty wrapper of `SemanticDatePicker`. Anyway, when the `onChange` handler will be called by `SemanticDatePicker`, it will actually write the state declared at `MyForm` level, and you can then safely read it in a method of `MyForm`.

The section **[Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)** from the official React documentation is addressing this particular use case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Michael. I've now read various articles on lifting state and that is definitely what I'm after. I understand the concept but still can't seem to actually make it work within my code for some reason.