# How to pass child prop to parent?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I've got some dynamic buttons that are a child component, and get assigned a `value="URL"` based off of my MongoDB. How do I go about passing that generated value to my parent/web component `src={currentSrc}`? When I assign it, it says that currentSrc is not defined?

Here's the `SizeOptions`:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export const SizeOptions = ({ size }) => {
  const sizeName = Object.keys(size);

  // Update Model Viewers Src
  function changeSize (){
    setSrc(currentSrc)
    console.log(currentSrc)
  }

  if (!sizeName) return <></>;

  return (
    <div>
        {size[sizeName].map((item) => (
          <button key={item} className='size' value={item} onClick={changeSize} currentSrc={item}>
            {sizeName}
          </button>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is the `ProductScreen`:

```js
import './ProductScreen.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

//Components
import { SizeOptions } from '../components/SizeOptions';

const [currentSrc, setSrc] = useState(size[sizeName][0])

const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {
return(
<div className='sizebuttons'>
  {product && (product.size || []).map((size, index) => (<SizeOptions  key={index} size={size} setSrc={currentSrc} changeSize={changeSize}/>))}
</div>
<div className="productscreen__right">
  <model-viewer
    id="model-viewer"
    src={currentSrc}
    alt={product.productName}
    ar
    ar-modes="scene-viewer quick-look"
    ar-placement="floor"
    shadow-intensity="1"
    camera-controls
    min-camera-orbit={product.mincameraorbit} 
    max-camera-orbit={product.maxcameraorbit}
    interaction-prompt="none">  
      <button slot="ar-button" className="ar-button">
        View in your space
      </button>
  </model-viewer>
</div>
)}
```

The rendered button:

[image: HTML]

I have more code inside my `ProductScreen`, I just tried to keep it as minimized as possible to try and make it easier to help me figure it out! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Small update, I re-organized my DB and edited my question to reflect it. I now am able to assign the model's URL to a `value=" "` on the dynamic buttons. So now just trying to figure out how to make the size change the `src=` on the model viewer to reflect the correct size selected.

Comment: I found I can get the array of the values when I `console.log(size[sizeName])`, so now I just need to figure out how I can pass those to the model-viewer src when clicked..

Comment: Small update, I've tried adding the useState inside of the SizeOptions.js file, but still no luck on finding a solution. I'm sure I'm maybe doing it wrong, but feel like I'm getting closer to the result I am wanting. Going to keep trying to mess with it.

Comment: Whenever I put `{currentSrc}` into the `src="{currentSrc)"` spot on model-viewer, it says it's not defined?

Comment: If you need access to `currentSrc` in the `ProductScreen` component you can move the `const [currentSrc, setSrc] = useState(size[sizeName][0])` state up to `ProductScreen` and pass it down to the `SizeOptions`

Comment: @RedMercury Okay, I understand what you mean, I will try it out and report back! Thank you very much!

Comment: @RedMercury Sorry for the late update! Got busy with other projects. But, okay I moved the `const [currentSrc, setSrc] = useState(size[sizeName][0])` to the `ProductScreen` page, as well as the `changeSize` function as it was throwing errors for that. But now it's saying `size` and `sizeName` are not defined on the `ProductScreen`. I've also tried moving the whole script over to the product page in hopes that would work, but sadly it did not. I'll keep messing around with it, but any other ideas by chance?

Comment: Just a suggestion, there may be an easier, simpler way of doing it: [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549); cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! I finally figured it out after many, many attempts.

So in order to pass from child to parent this is what I came up with:

`SizeOptions.js`

```js
export const SizeOptions = ({ size, changeSrc }) => {
    const sizeName = Object.keys(size);

    if (!sizeName) return <></>;

    return (
    <div>
        {size[sizeName].map((url) => (
            <button key={url} className='size' value={url} onClick={() => changeSrc(url)}>
                {sizeName}
            </button>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SizeOptions;
```

`ProductScreen.js`

```js
import './ProductScreen.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

// Actions
import { getProductDetails } from "../redux/actions/productActions";

//Components
import { SizeOptions } from '../components/SizeOptions';

const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.getProductDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
    
    const [ src, setSrc ] = useState("Default URL")

return(

    <div className='sizebuttons'>
        {product && (product.size || []).map((size, index) => (<SizeOptions  key={index} size=  {size} changeSrc={src => setSrc(src)}/>))}
    </div>
              
    <model-viewer
        id="model-viewer"
        src={src}
        alt={product.productName}
        ar
        ar-modes="scene-viewer quick-look"
        ar-placement="floor"
        shadow-intensity="1"
        camera-controls
        min-camera-orbit={product.mincameraorbit} 
        max-camera-orbit={product.maxcameraorbit}
        interaction-prompt="none">  
        <button slot="ar-button" className="ar-button">
            View in your space
        </button>
    </model-viewer>
)};
```

The only issue now is how to make the "Default URL" actually be a URL as right now if I put `{src}` there, it says it cannot do that before the component is rendered.