# Testing in React: How to set a state from testfile?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test a component and it contains conditional rendering. So if a state is *true*, the JSX-HTML should render, if *false* not.

If I want to test this by using **Jest, Enyzme, React-Testing-Library** how should I proceed?

I have a  component, its implementation details do not matter for this topic. Just be aware, that it contains

```
const [isBlocked, setIsBlocked] = useState(false);
```

And for my test, I want to set this to true.

```
describe('rendering DiffWindow', () => {
    it("renders HeaderBar components without crash", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow( < HeaderBar /> );

        // HOW TO SET HERE THE STATE?
      
        expect(wrapper.find('.header-is-there').exists()).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

Comment: State will have to be initialised via a prop.

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549), cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the implementation details, there are two situations in your problem：

**1. `State` is managed by the component itself**

For `boolean` state, the initial value is `false`, followed by an API call to change its value to `true`, or an event handler triggered by user interaction.

You need to set up a mock HTTP server to response the API call, or use [fireEvent[eventName]](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/) to simulate user interaction. Assert component view changes when state changes.

**2. `State` is managed by the parent component**

This case is mentioned by @blessenm. Generally, the state will have to be initialized by a prop passed from a parent component.

You can pass the prop with different values to change the view of the component.