# How do I get the value from the child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component that I am importing into a page:

```
function CodeVerify(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const ref = useBlurOnFulfill({value, cellCount: CELL_COUNT});
  const [propsCV, getCellOnLayoutHandler] = useClearByFocusCell({
    value,
    setValue,
  });

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        Enter the code sent to your number 
      </Text>
      <CodeField
        ref={ref}
        {...propsCV}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={setValue}
        cellCount={CELL_COUNT}
        rootStyle={styles.codeFiledRoot}
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        textContentType="oneTimeCode"
        renderCell={({index, symbol, isFocused}) => (
          <View
            // Make sure that you pass onLayout={getCellOnLayoutHandler(index)} prop to root component of "Cell"
            onLayout={getCellOnLayoutHandler(index)}
            key={index}
            style={[styles.cellRoot, isFocused && styles.focusCell]}>
            <Text style={styles.cellText}>
              {symbol || (isFocused ? <Cursor /> : null)}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

On the page, I render the component `<CodeVerify />`

How do I get the component's Value from the CodeVerify component?

Comment: what is genus ?

Comment: How do I get the component's Value from the CodeVerify component?*

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This might help: [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `lifted up` your state from `child` to `parent` and then pass that data Here is the example:

**Parent Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Child from "./Child";

function CParent(props) {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

    function setOpeningValue(value) {
        console.log('From Child to Parent:' + value);
        setValue(value);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Child setOpeningValue={setOpeningValue}/>
        </div>
    );
}
export default CParent;
```

> Here we are passing `setOpeningValue` using the props like `setOpeningValue={setOpeningValue}`. From child component we are calling `setOpeningValue` with a value in `parameter` so that we can received that `parameter` into `parent component`.

**Child Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

// Child to Parent communication
function Child(props) {
    const {setOpeningValue} = props;
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    function clickHandler() {
        setOpeningValue(`changes is ${value}`);
    }

    function changeHandler(event) {
        setValue(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={changeHandler} />
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>pass data to parent</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Child;
```