# Hide Child Component Element After onClick using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm new to React, learning by coding, here i have component A, which has select element with menuItems (all material ui), when user clicks select element and chooses from drop down, right after user has chosen whole component should go display:none, is this possible ? i mean user should not be able to see select element anymore on the page

English is not my mother language, so there might be mistakes.

suggestions/help is appreciated.

component A:

```js
const A: React.FC<AProps> = (props) => {
  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    const site = e.target.value as string;
    dispatch(changeActiveSite(site));
    if (site) {
      dispatch(getAnalysers(site));
    } else {
      dispatch(clearSiteData(site));
    }
  };

  const sites = [
    {
      ident: "",
      name: "None",
    },
  ].concat(sitess);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="site-select-input-label">site</InputLabel>
        <Select
          id="site-select"
          value={currentSiteId}
          labelId="site-select-input-label"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        >
          {sites.map((site) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={site.ident} value={site.ident}>
                {site.name}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

that component is in component B like this:  `<div > <A site={site} /> </div>`

Comment: Have your child component's `render() {...}` have a `if(this.state.hidden) { return ''; }` line.  Then just set the state, `child.setState({'hidden':true})`.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger could you possibly give answer using my code ? so i can accept

Comment: Hey hey, sure, posted, let me know if anything isn't working afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine your `MenuItem.js`, specifically, its `render()` and `constructor()`.  You'll want it to be able to be hidden/not-displayed, or visible/displayed.  Use a state attribute for `hidden` to control this, your render will probably look like...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        'hidden':false,
    };
}

render () {
    if(this.state.hidden) {
        return '';
    }
    
    return (
        <div
            onClick={(e) => this.handleOnClick(e)}
        >
            {this.props.value}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Notice I also added a `handleOnClick(e)` handler up above!  That will simply call `this.setState({'hidden':true})`, so like...

```
handleOnClick(e) {
    this.setState({'hidden':true});
}
```

I have an answer to a similar question elsewhere, if it might also help: [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549)

Comment: could you use Hooks instead of class ?

Comment: @walee: Hey, that was just meant as an example.  You never provided the code for your `MenuItem`, so, I'm just guessing, but you *probably already have it coded, using hooks, since you use hooks*, since it's broken, right?  Just update that to have a `hidden` attribute.  I'm trying to just answer your primary question, not get bogged down in stylings.