# How to pass props to HOC from calling component - React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, azure-ad-msal, higher-order-components

i created new PublicClientApplication in my index.tsx. Now I want to pass this to my withAuthHOC. This HOC is using by the App.tsx. So i want to use the PublicClientApplication (pca props) in HOC. How can I do it?

My AppProps.tsx:

```
export type AppProps = {
    pca: IPublicClientApplication
  };
```

My index.tsx:

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App pca={msalInstance} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My App.tsx:

```
  const App = ({pca}:AppProps) => {
  return (
      <MainRoutes />
  );
}

export default withAuthHOC(App);
```

My withAuthHOC.tsx:

```
const withAuthHOC = (WrappedComponent: React.FunctionComponent) => {
    return () => {
        useMsalRedirect();

        return (
            <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
                <AuthenticatedValidation />
                <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                    <WrappedComponent />
                </AuthenticatedTemplate>
            </MsalProvider>
        );
    }
};

export default withAuthHOC;
```

Comment: Hi, I have an answer to a similar question, hope this helps: [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get it on props of the HOC

```
const withAuthHOC = (WrappedComponent: React.FunctionComponent) => {
    return (props) => {

        const {pca} = props; // get pca form props

        useMsalRedirect();

        return (
            <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
                <AuthenticatedValidation />
                <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                    <WrappedComponent />
                </AuthenticatedTemplate>
            </MsalProvider>
        );
    }
};

export default withAuthHOC;
```