# How does React update a component and its children after a state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

I am watching [Paul O Shannessy - Building React From Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MAD4Oly9yg&t=293s&ab_channel=ReactRally)

And I understand the mounting process very well but I have hard day trying to understand how React update a component and its children

The reconciler controls the update process by this method:

```
function receiveComponent(component, element) {
  let prevElement = component._currentElement;
  if (prevElement === element) {
    return;
  }

  component.receiveComponent(element);
}
```

`Component.receiveComponent`

```
 receiveComponent(nextElement) {
    this.updateComponent(this._currentElement, nextElement);
  }
```

and this is the `Component.updateComponent` method:

```
  updateComponent(prevElement, nextElement) {
    if (prevElement !== nextElement) {
      // React would call componentWillReceiveProps here
    }

    // React would call componentWillUpdate here

    // Update instance data
    this._currentElement = nextElement;
    this.props = nextElement.props;
    this.state = this._pendingState;
    this._pendingState = null;

    let prevRenderedElement = this._renderedComponent._currentElement;
    let nextRenderedElement = this.render();
 
    if (shouldUpdateComponent(prevRenderedElement, nextRenderedElement)) {
      Reconciler.receiveComponent(this._renderedComponent, nextRenderedElement);
    } 
  }
```

This is the part of the code that updates the component after state change, and i assume that it should update the children too, but i can't understand how this code achieves that, in the mounting process React instantiate components to dive deeper in the tree but this doesn't happen here, we need to find the first HTML element then we can change our strategy and update that HTML element in another place in the code, and I can't find any way to find any HTML elements this way.

Finding the first HTML is the way to stop this endless recursion and logically this is what I expect from the code, to stop recursion the same way in the mounting process, but in mounting, this demanded component instantiation so we can delegate to the reconciler that will discover that we are dealing with a wrapper instance of an HTML element not a wrapper instance of a custom component then React can place that HTML element in the DOM.

I can't understand how the code works in the update process. this code as I see won't dive deeper in the tree and I think won't update the children and can't let React find the first HTML element so React can update the DOM element, **isn't it?**

This is the code repo  on [Github](https://github.com/zpao/building-react-from-scratch)

Comment: I have an answer to a similar question, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549), cheers!

Comment: @HoldOffHunger thank you for reply but this is not even related to my question

Comment: the render of the parent would be calling a createElement of each child, which would imply a render

Comment: @TiagoCoelho
can you please answer the question in detail using code snippets in the repo??..i only need code explaining because it is confusing to me

Comment: @CodeEagle done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I created a codesandbox to dig in

Here is [the codesandbox I created](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-shannon-339cs?file=/src/index.js)

and here's a short [recording](https://recordit.co/jt9l0CWDgQ) of me opening the debugger and seeing the call stack.

#### How it works

Starting from where you left off, Component.updateComponent:

```
  updateComponent(prevElement, nextElement) {
  //...
    if (shouldUpdateComponent(prevRenderedElement, nextRenderedElement)) {
      Reconciler.receiveComponent(this._renderedComponent, nextRenderedElement);
  //...
```

in the `Component.updateComponent` method `Reconciler.receiveComponent` is called which calls `component.receiveComponent(element);`

Now, this `component` refers to `this._renderedComponent` and is not an instance of `Component` but of `DOMComponentWrapper`

and here's the receiveComponent method of `DOMComponentWrapper`:

```
  receiveComponent(nextElement) {
    this.updateComponent(this._currentElement, nextElement);
  }

  updateComponent(prevElement, nextElement) {
    // debugger;
    this._currentElement = nextElement;
    this._updateDOMProperties(prevElement.props, nextElement.props);
    this._updateDOMChildren(prevElement.props, nextElement.props);
  }
```

Then `_updateDOMChildren` ends up calling the children `render` method.

here's a call stack from the codesandbox I created to dig in.

[image: call stack from setState until child render]

#### How do we end up in DOMComponentWrapper

in the `Component`'s `mountComponent` method we have:

```
let renderedComponent = instantiateComponent(renderedElement);
this._renderedComponent = renderedComponent;
```

and in `instantiateComponent` we have:

```
  let type = element.type;

  let wrapperInstance;
  if (typeof type === 'string') {
    wrapperInstance = HostComponent.construct(element);
  } else if (typeof type === 'function') {
    wrapperInstance = new element.type(element.props);
    wrapperInstance._construct(element);
  } else if (typeof element === 'string' || typeof element === 'number') {
    wrapperInstance = HostComponent.constructTextComponent(element);
  }

  return wrapperInstance;
```

HostComponent is being injected with `DOMComponentWrapper` in `dilithium.js` main file:

```
HostComponent.inject(DOMComponentWrapper);
```

HostComponent is only a kind of proxy meant to invert control and allow different Hosts in React.

here's the `inject` method:

```
function inject(impl) {
  implementation = impl;
}
```

and the `construct` method:

```
function construct(element) {
  assert(implementation);

  return new implementation(element);
}
```

#### When we have no DOMComponentWrapper

If we are updating a chain of Non Host Components like:

```
const Child = <div>Hello</div>

const Parent = () => <Child />
```

How does `Child` get rendered from an update to `Parent`?

the `Parent` `Component` has the following:

- _renderedComponent which is an instance of `Child`(which is also a `Component`)

  - renderedComponent has an instance of Child because it gets the type of the "root" Element (the one returned by the render method)

so `Reconciler.receiveComponent(this._renderedComponent, nextRenderedElement)` will be calling `component.receiveComponent(element)` of the Child which in turn calls `this.updateComponent(this._currentElement, nextElement);` (of `Child`) which calls it's `render` method (`let nextRenderedElement = this.render();`)

Comment: Thank you,  this is exactly what i need, some code explanation, but something is still confusing to me, i understand how we end up in `DOMComponentWrapper` in the mount process, but still cant understand how we end up in `DOMComponentWrapper` in updating process, ..won't this two lines of code lead to endless recursion   ```if (shouldUpdateComponent(prevRenderedElement, nextRenderedElement)) {
      Reconciler.receiveComponent(this._renderedComponent, nextRenderedElement);```  and we won't never end up in `DOMComponentWrapper ` again to update the DOM element

Comment: You have explained that `this.renderedComponent` is an instance of `DOMComponentWrapper` instead of `Component` which i can't digest, this really solve the puzzle for me, but can't understand how this come, 

``` let renderedElement = this.render();
    let renderedComponent = instantiateComponent(renderedElement); ```

which can be an instance of `Component`

Comment: You are right, instantiateComponent can return an instance of Component, the catch is that renderedElement is the root element of what this Component renders.
So it will refer to a child and not to the same component

Comment: @CodeEagle I added a section indicating what happens in the case where we have a simple chain of `Component`s

Comment: but what if that parent component render another custom component which in turn render another custom component which finally render a real DOM element, what if the update started in the grandparent??

Comment: that's covered in this case... please read the last section I added (When we have no DOMComponentWrapper) your case fits there

Comment: sorry for being unable to understand this part till now it is actually my problem that drove me to ask the question but how `receiveComponent` of all children in the chain would work despite we always will have a single instance of `_renderedComponent` so why i mentioned in the question, how we would end up in `DOMComponentWrapper` without instantiation children i think the same `receiveComponent` method of the same `_renderedComponent` would always work and this would lead to endless recursion, i know what you are saying is the solution for everything but i still can't absorb how this happens

Comment: it happens because render() returns an element corresponding to the first child (root child of this component) and later instantiate uses the element type of that rendered element, which will be the component type, and so at each level the recursion will be referring to the child until we have a DOMComponent element (a string)

Comment: here is the problem and thank you for your patience with me, the render result would not be instantiated so we have no renderedComponent for it so we will not have `receiveComponent` method to use!!!

Comment: is it possible that the renderedComponent instance receive a new child in the chain with each cycle??..it would be a strange logic to corrupt the instance we have which carry all info about the component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241258/discussion-between-code-eagle-and-tiago-coelho).

Comment: another thing,your explanation imply that `prevRenderedElement` and `nextRenderedElement`  are parent and child??..if that true, why we even need to compare parent and child  in `shouldUpdateComponent` to decide between updating or remounting??..so `prevRenderedElement` and `nextRenderedElement` must be the same element with the updating difference!!

Comment: this confirm that the same `render()` method work in each cycle of the recursion..this code is so confusing

Comment: can you please take a look on our chat and read my last message?

Comment: thank you i accepted the answer and started a new bounty to reward it, thanks for your patience and for this great answer

Answer (score 1):

React completely copy the actual DOM and create the virtual DOM in javascript. In our application whenever we update any of the data that ends up being rendered in our components, React does not rerender the entire DOM. It only affects the thing that matters. So react actually copies the virtual DOM again. This time it applies the changes to the data that got updated.

[image]

It will make the change in the red component and then it will compare this virtual DOM to the old DOM. It will see the different part. Then it will apply the DOM changes only to that different component.

The updating phase starts if props or the state changes. If the data at the top level changes:

[image]

If it is passing that data down to its children, all the children are going to be rerendered. If the state of the component at the mid-level gets changed:

[image]

This time only its children will get rerendered. React will rerender any part of the tree below that node. Because the data that generates the children components' view actually sits at the parent component(mid-level one). But anything above it, the parent or the siblings will not rerender. because data does not affect them. this concept is called `Unidirectional Data Flow`.

You can see in action in chrome browser. chose the rendering and then enable the `painting flushing` option

[image]

If you make any change on the page, you will see that updated components will be flashed.

### UPDATING PHASE

**componentWillReceiveProps** method is invoked first in the component lifecycle's updating phase. It is called when a component receives new properties from its parent component. With this method we compare the current component's properties using the this.props object with the next component's properties
using the `nextElement.props` object. Based on this comparison, we can choose to update the component's state using the `this.setState()` function, which will NOT trigger
an additional render in this scenario.

Note that no matter how many times you call `this.setState()` in the `componentWillReceiveProps()` method, it won't trigger any additional renders of that component. React does an internal optimization where it batches the state updates together.

**shouldComponentUpdated** dictates if the components should rerender or not. By default, all class components will rerender whenever the props they receive or their state change. this method can prevent the default behavior by returning `False`. In this method, existing props and state values get compared with the next props and state values and return boolean to let React know whether the component should update or not. this method is for performance optimization. If it returns `False` `componentWillUpdate()`, `render()` and `componentDidUpdate()` wont get called.

The **componentWillUpdate()** method is called immediately before React updates the DOM. It gets two arguments: `nextProps` and `nextState`. You can use these arguments to prepare for the DOM update. However, you cannot use `this.setState()` in the `componentWillUpdate()` method.

After calling the componentWillUpdate() method, React invokes the `render()` method that performs the DOM update. Then, the `componentDidUpdate()` method is called.

The `componentDidUpdate()` method is called immediately after React updates the DOM. It gets these two arguments: `prevProps` and `prevState`. We use this method to interact with the updated DOM or perform any post-render operations. For example, in a counter example, counter number is increased in `componentDidUpdate`.

After `componentDidUpdate()` is called, the updating cycle ends. A new cycle is started when a component's state is updated or a parent component passes new properties. Or when you call the `forceUpdate()` method, it triggers a new updating cycle, but skips the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method (this method is for optimization) on a component that
triggered the update. However, `shouldComponentUpdate()` is called on all the child components as per the usual updating phase. Try to avoid using the `forceUpdate()` method as much as possible; this will promote your application's maintainability

Comment: i really understand how React works in theory, but my question is about how the code in the  Paul O Shannessy talk achieve the update because i can't understand how this code update the component and its children,..my question is about React internals not the theory

Comment: @CodeEagle I updated the answer. but componentWillUpdate gets called after shouldUpdate not before

Comment: I am really sorry, but u still can't understand what i am really looking for, i understand this process well, i am searching for something simpler, the code explanation, the code in the repo and the video, it is confusing to me, it doesn't contain `forceUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps`, just how the code of updating components work together, can u please read my question well??

Comment: @CodeEagle that code is wrong. // React would call componentWillUpdate here// componentWillUpdate gets called after shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: @CodeEagle Because shouldComponentUpdate decides if the component should be updated or not. It makes the decision. how come componentWillUpdate can get called before it?

Comment: the code is not wrong, `shouldUpdateComponent` is not the same as `shouldComponentUpdate`,  `shouldUpdateComponent` is just a util that decide if the component will update or blow away all the subtree and remount again, check the github repo and you will find that util in a mdoule called shouldUpdateComponent.js

Answer (score 1):

Another answer might be the structure of the Fiber tree. During execution, react renders a `ReactComponent` into an object made out of `ReactNode`s and props. These `ReactNode`s are assembled into a `FiberNode` tree (which might be the in memory representation of the virutal dom?).

In the `FiberNode` tree, depending on the traversal algorithm (children first, sibling first, etc), React always has a single "next" node to continue. So, React will dive deeper into the tree, and update `FiberNode`s, as it goes along.

If we take the same example,

```
function App() {
  return <div>
    <Parent>
      <Child01/>
      <Child01/>
    </Parent>
    <Child03/>
  </div>
}

function Parent({children}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  return <div>
    <button onClick={x => x+1)>click</button>
    <Child02 />
    {children}
  </div>
}
```

Which React will transform into this FiberNode tree:

```
node01 = { type: App, return: null, child: node02, sibling: null }
node02 = { type: 'div', return: node01, child: node03, sibling: null }
node03 = { type: Parent, return: node02, child: node05(?), sibling: node04 }
node04 = { type: Child03, return: node02, child: null, sibling: null }
node05 = { type: Child01, return: node03, child: null, sibling: node06 }
node06 = { type: Child01, return: node03, child: null, sibling: null }

// Parent will spawn its own FiberTree,
node10 = { type: 'div', return: node02, child: node11, sibling: null }
node11 = { type: 'button', return: node10, child: null, sibling: node12 }
node12 = { type: Child02, return: node10, child: null, sibling: node05 }
```

I might have missed something (ie. node03's child might be node10), but the idea is this - React always have a single node (the 'next' node) to render when it traverses the fiber tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think React not re-render parent component first instead of that, React re-render child component first.

Example: A (parent) -> B (child) -> C (child of B)
When A update state C (re-render) -> B -> A

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but i think this is not related to the question, the question is about how react works internally and how it really updates the components, and i found some code that simplify the real codebase of react but i can't understand it and can't understand how it really updates the component and dive deeper in the tree updating children components

Answer (score 0):

Hey Consider using a **Tree** data structure for your need, ReactJs follows a unidirectional manner of Updating the state i.e. As soon as the there is a Change in the parent state then all the children which are passed on the props that are residing in the Parent Component are updated once and for all!
Consider using something known as **Depth First Search** as an algo option which will find you the Node that connects to the parent and once you reach that node , you check for the state and if there is a deviation from the state variables that are shared by the parent you can update them!

Note : This may all seem a bit theoretical but if you could do something remotely close to this thing you will have created a way to update components just how react does!

Answer (score 0):

I found out experimentally that React will only re-render elements if it have to, which is always, except for `{children}` and [`React.memo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Using children correctly, together with batched dom updates makes a very efficient and smooth user experience.

consider this case:

```
function App() {
  return <div>
    <Parent>
      <Child01/>
      <Child01/>
    </Parent>
    <Child03/>
  </div>
}

function Parent({children}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  return <div>
    <button onClick={x => x+1)>click</button>
    <Child02 />
    {children}
  </div>
}
```

when clicking on the button, you will get the following:

```
- button click
- setState(...), add Parent to dirty list
- start re-rendering all dirty nodes
- Parent rerenders
- Child02 rerenders
- DONE
```

Note that

- Parent (`app`) and sibling (`Child03`) nodes will not get re-rendered, or you'll end up with a re-render recursion.
- `Parent` is re-rendered because its state has changed, so its output has to be recalculated.
- `{children}` have not been affected by this change, so it stays the same. (unless a context is involved, but that's a different mechanism).
- finally, `<Child02 />` has been marked dirty, because that part of the virtual dom has been touched. While it's trivial for us to see it was not effected, the only way React could verify it is by comparing props, which is not done by default!
- the only way to prevent Child02 from rendering is wrapping it with `React.memo`, which might be slower than just re-rendring it.